# Selecting multiple nodes with Spring Data Neo4j @Query

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Using Cypher, multiple nodes are selected by listing them separated by commas:

`START n=node(1, 2, 3) RETURN n`

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-start.html#start-multiple-nodes-by-id

I would like to use this with Spring Data @Query but it does not work:

```
@Query("start person=node({0}) match (person)-[:has_friends]->(friend) return friend")
private Iterable<Person> friends(Iterable<Person> persons);
```

**Edit:**
Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Person cannot be cast to org.neo4j.graphdb.Node
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.AsOneStartBranch.toBranches(AsOneStartBranch.java:65)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.AsOneStartBranch.<init>(AsOneStartBranch.java:59)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.BidirectionalTraverserIterator.<init>(BidirectionalTraverserIterator.java:81)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.BidirectionalTraverserImpl.instantiateIterator(BidirectionalTraverserImpl.java:44)
  at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.traversal.AbstractTraverser.iterator(AbstractTraverser.java:83)
  at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.matching.BidirectionalTraversalMatcher.findMatchingPaths(BidirectionalTraversalMatcher.scala:73)
  at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.TraversalMatchPipe$$anonfun$createResults$1.apply(TraversalMatchPipe.scala:32)
  at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.TraversalMatchPipe$$anonfun$createResults$1.apply(TraversalMatchPipe.scala:29)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$21.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$21.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
  at org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:138)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$19.hasNext(Iterator.scala:334)
  at scala.collection.JavaConversions$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(JavaConversions.scala:562)
  at org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you pass in a collection / list instead of an iterable?

Comment: No I have the same error. I've added the stacktrace.

Comment: Should work if you pass in a collection of the nodeIds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current version of SDN this query should work:

```
@Query("(person)-[:has_friends]->(friend) where id(person) IN {0} return friend")
private Iterable<Person> friends(Iterable<Person> persons);
```

Comment: i got this personnaly :ERROR [stderr] (taskExecutor-7) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

17:35:11,787 ERROR [stderr] (taskExecutor-7)  at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.markAsRollbackOnly(TopLevelTransaction.java:93)

Comment: Found out what was the problem. Instead of Iterable for the return type I use a List. Actually I think that with the iterable object neo4j tries to do a sort of lazy loading (the function hasNext doesn't work) and as i'm out of my transaction the hasnext function try to fetch the next element and NPE on getTransaction in the file TopLevelTransaction in neo4j kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You should start from `node(*)` instead of `node(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `Person` is annotated with `@NodeEntitiy`. As the stacktrace states, `Node`(s) (*NodeId(s)* (`Long`), work as well) are expected, if you want to substitute it for the `{0}` in `start person=node({0}) ...`